# Good practical way to do loop within loop to show child custom type using a template code

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I'm using Version WP e-Commerce plugin 3.8.12.1

I used a custom post type "event" with multiple value field "event_photos" and the field type is wpsc-product.

To show a single "event" use single-event.php :

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php
                /* Include the single view for the event. 
                 */             
                include TEMPLATEPATH.'/event-templates/single.php';

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

To show a list of products of a custom type "event" use "/event-templates/single.php" :

```
<div class="entry-show-products">
            <?php $event_photos_obj = get_field('event_photos'); //Show product in a list
                    if( $event_photos_obj ) :
                        echo '<ul>';
                        foreach ($event_photos_obj as $products) :
                            setup_postdata($products);?>
                            <li>
                                <?php
                                $target_product = get_field('event_picture_photo', $products->ID);
                                ?>
                                <div class="imagecol">
                                    <?php 
                                        if ( wpsc_the_product_thumbnail(0,0,$products->ID) ) : ?>
                                                <a rel="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_title(); ?>" class="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_image_link_classes(
                                                ); ?>" href="<?php echo esc_url( wpsc_the_product_image(0,0,$products->ID) ); ?>">
                                                    <img class="product_image" id="product_image_<?php echo $products->ID ?>" alt="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_title(); ?>" src="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_thumbnail(0,0,$products->ID); ?>"/>
                                                </a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div><!--close imagecol-->
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach;
                        echo '</ul>';
                    else :                  
                        echo "Δεν υπάρχει φωτογραφία";
                    endif; ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-show-photo -->
```

My question is how to tell wp to index in a specific product and then using the template code "wpsc-single_product.php" :

```
    <div id="single_product_page_container">

    <?php
        // Breadcrumbs
        wpsc_output_breadcrumbs();

        // Plugin hook for adding things to the top of the products page, like the live search
        do_action( 'wpsc_top_of_products_page' );
    ?>

    <div class="single_product_display group">
<?php
        /**
         * Start the product loop here.
         * This is single products view, so there should be only one
         */

        ?>
                    <div class="imagecol">
                        <?php if ( wpsc_the_product_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                                <a rel="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_title(); ?>" class="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_image_link_classes(); ?>" href="<?php echo esc_url( wpsc_the_product_image() ); ?>">
                                    <img class="product_image" id="product_image_<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>" alt="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_title(); ?>" src="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_thumbnail(); ?>"/>
                                </a>
                                <?php
                                if ( function_exists( 'gold_shpcrt_display_gallery' ) )
                                    echo gold_shpcrt_display_gallery( wpsc_the_product_id() );
                                ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wpsc_the_product_permalink() ); ?>">
                                    <img class="no-image" id="product_image_<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>" alt="No Image" title="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_title(); ?>" src="<?php echo WPSC_CORE_THEME_URL; ?>wpsc-images/noimage.png" width="<?php echo get_option('product_image_width'); ?>" height="<?php echo get_option('product_image_height'); ?>" />
                                    </a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div><!--close imagecol-->


        </div><!--close single_product_display-->

        <?php echo wpsc_product_comments(); ?>

<?php do_action( 'wpsc_theme_footer' ); ?>

</div><!--close single_product_page_container-->
```

Is it better way to use WP_Query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
global $post;

  foreach ($event_photos_obj as $post) :

  ...
  ...
  // set up product in order to use native wordpress api
   setup_postdata($post);

 /* Include the single view for the product (photo). */
 include  .....


 endforeach;
 wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

my mistake my code is that setup_postdata with $product instead of $post as the tutorial said : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata

This is one way, the second way uses  WP_Query http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
but in my case I don't need because I have already the object from the WP E-Commenrce with his functions and everything.